# How to play WMV with omxplayer?

Tags: raspbian, video

I have WMV files (among others) omxplayer won't play. What to do?

Comment: You asked this only to answer it yourself without *any* delay? Sounds like a cheap shot at getting reputation...

Comment: @RenéWolferink Not at all; this is in the spirit of [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)! Besides, is it cheap, really? It's information relevant to Pi users but not available on [raspberrypi.SE] yet. If it's useful, people will upvote; can't see the harm in that. Also, there may well be other feasible solutions. (If I wanted to see high rep counts, I'd invest more time in my [cs.SE] activity. ;))

Comment: Did not know that. But now I do. All the best to you for adding information. :)

Comment: @ChetanBhargava Have you read my comment above, and the blog entry I link to?

Comment: @ChetanBhargava Yea, that would be below, in my answer. (The answer to my question is "no", apparently?)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of codecs not shipped with Raspbian. You can do two things.

- [Buy a license.](http://www.raspberrypi.com/license-keys/)
- Get rid of incompatible files. For instance, use a more powerful computer and run

  ```
  ffmpeg -i "some video.wmv" -qscale 0 "some video.mkv"
  ```

  which will convert the video nicely. For Debian derivates (like Ubuntu), `ffmpeg` comes in a package of the same name.

  While you are at it, you may want to add subtitles (note: only SRT works with `omxplayer` at this time!) to the video; support for external subtitle files is only now coming to `omxplayer`. Just give an additional `-i "subtitles.srt"` to `ffmpeg`.